# undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category() cmake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have an undefined reference while trying to compile my `Qt5` project.
I am usually pretty confident with using `CMake` but this time I have a strange error that I can't figure out:

`undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()`

`/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'`

My configurations are:

1. `gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`
2. `Qt5.15`
3. `cmake version 3.16.3`
4. After typing `whereis boost` the outcome was`boost: /usr/include/boost` and after applying the great power of `dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'` :) the version is `Version: 1.71.0.0ubuntu2`

I don't understand what is happening, below an example of how my `CMakeLists.txt` is structured:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project(projectA)

set (OpenCV_DIR /home/to/opencv/build)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package( Boost COMPONENTS system thread filesystem REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5PrintSupport)

#make them into headers
qt5_wrap_ui (UI_HDRS  ${UI})

add_executable(projectA main/main.cpp ui/qdarkstyle/style.qrc ${SRCS} ${UI_HDRS} ${UI_SRCS})
target_link_libraries (projectA Qt5::Widgets  ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS}  Qt5::PrintSupport)

add_library(projectA_lib SHARED ${SRCS} ${UI_HDRS})
target_include_directories (projectA_lib PUBLIC "src/" "ui/")
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries (projectA_lib Qt5::Widgets ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I have searched and applied solutions I saw on all possible sources I was able to find such as:

[This source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154639/undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category-when-adding-boost-asi) but that didn't work.

Also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513269/cmake-undefined-reference-to-boost-library) it seems that this solution shall be applied:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

# the call to include_directories is now useless:
# the Boost::system imported target used below
# embeds the include directories

project(APP C CXX)
add_executable(APP src.cpp)
target_link_libraries(APP Boost::system)
```

However that also didn't do any specific benefits to finding the solution.

Other posts I consulted were [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154639/undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category-when-adding-boost-asi), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584373/undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category-even-though-it-exists-in-l) but no answer was provided.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812866/cant-link-boost-1-63-0-through-cmake) was useful but that also didn't provide any advice that  didn't already know.

Thanks for pointing to the right direction and trying to find a solution.

Comment: `-lboost_system` should not be in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: Please, show **complete error message**: It should include a library (executable) which is being built, paths, etc.  Assuming you use `make` for build the project, run it with `VERBOSE=1` argument: that way **exact linker command line** will be printed.

Comment: And please do a verbose build (e.g. `make VERBOSE=1`) to see what  commands are executed, complete with flags and options.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes I noticed but that was not the source of the error. I deleted it for completeness. Thanks for point that out though!

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I compile with `Qt5` debugger. How do I make a 'VERBOSE' build specifically?

Comment: When you say "Qt5 debugger" do you mean the [Qt Creator IDE](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes exactly

Comment: I don't know enough about Qt Creator to be able to tell, but you might try setting the `VERBOSE` environment variable (to e.g. `1`) before running `cmake` to generate the IDE project file.

Comment: Googling for "qt creator cmake verbose build" [gives](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qt-creator/2015-January/004356.html) Projects mode > Build > “Details” of Qbs build step > tick on “show command lines”.